# disable specific dates in single month of every year jquery datepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i want to disable a specific date from a specific month of every year in datepicker from Jquery Ui.
for example:
disable auguest(month) 15(date) of every year in datetime picker

Comment: Use `beforeShowDay`, eg. like this guy did -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964662

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option.

```
$("selector").datepicker({
    ...
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var month = date.getMonth()+1; // +1 because JS months start at 0
        var day = date.getDate();
        return [!(month == 8 && day == 15), ""];
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j737R/1/)